# AWS Java SDK Transfer manager downloads only folder structure

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager

When I tried to download all files of a specific folder from S3 using KeyPrefix, It downloads only the directory structure and not the files inside it.

Below is the code
TransferManager xfer_mgr = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().build();

```
    File a = new File("./");
    try {
        GetObjectRequest gor = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, "folder3");
        MultipleFileDownload xfer = xfer_mgr.downloadDirectory(
                bucketName, null, a);

    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("done...............");

    xfer_mgr.shutdownNow();
```

Am I missing anything in the code, or Any permissions has to be added?
Any Suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved It. 
Transfer manager downloads folder structure first and then all the files inside.

So the Solution is:
Making MultipleFileDownload xfer to 'waitForCompletion'.

Adding a line
*xfer.waitForCompletion()* solved the problem.